# Determining bound states for delta function potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I'm working on a problem out of Griffith's Intro to QM 2nd Ed. and it's asking to find the bound states for for the potential $V(x)=-\alpha[\delta(x+a)+\delta(x-a)]$ This is what I'm doing so far:

\begin{equation}
\mbox{for $x\lt-a$:}\hspace{1cm}\psi=Ae^{\kappa a}\\
\mbox{for $-a\lt x\lt a$}\hspace{1cm}\psi=Be^{-\kappa x}+Ce^{\kappa x}\\
\mbox{and for $x\gt a$:}\hspace{1cm}\psi=De^{-\kappa a}
\end{equation}

However, this is what the solution reads:
\begin{equation}
\mbox{for $x\lt a$:}\hspace{1cm}\psi=Ae^{-\kappa a}\\
\mbox{for $-a\lt x\lt a$}\hspace{1cm}\psi=B(e^{\kappa x}+e^{-\kappa x})\\
\mbox{and for $x\lt-a$:}\hspace{1cm}\psi=Ae^{\kappa a}
\end{equation}

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong - why they are getting the coefficients they are - and what I should be doing? Maybe go over the general way of approaching these kind of problems? I'm also wondering why they don't have the case for $x>a$?

${\bf New}$ ${\bf Question}$

After this I am trying to figure out what $\Delta\left(\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)$ is. Integrating the potential part of SWE and taking the limit as $\epsilon$ approaches $\pm a$I get:
\begin{equation}
\Delta\left(\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)=-\frac{2m}{\hbar ^2}\left[\alpha\psi(a)+\alpha\psi(-a)\right]
\end{equation}
but the solution reads $\Delta\left(\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)=-\frac{2m\alpha}{\hbar^2}\psi(a)$
I think I'm close but not sure how they got their result. Do you see what I'm doing? Can you correct where I made any mistakes?

Comment: There's a typo.   The first line should read $x>a$.  But what was your solution?  Your start is ok.  Where did you go from there?

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong

You're not doing anything wrong but you haven't taken the next logical step.

The potential is an *even* function so there (may) be both an even and an odd solution (proving this is also a problem in this chapter of the textbook).

For an even solution, and using your coefficients, we require

$$A = D$$

and

$$B = C$$

It turns out that there is always an even solution but there may not be an odd solution when $a$ is *small enough*.

Comment: after this I am trying to figure out what $\Delta\left(\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)$ is. Integrating the potential part of SWE and taking the limit as $\epsilon$ approaches $\pm a$I get:
\begin{equation}
\Delta\left(\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)=-\frac{2m}{\hbar ^2}\left[\alpha\psi(a)+\alpha\psi(-a)\right]
\end{equation}
but the solution reads $\Delta\left(\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)=-\frac{2m\alpha}{\hbar^2}\psi(a)$
I think I'm close but not sure how they got their result. Do you see what I'm doing? Can you correct where I made any mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

You have started with the correct functions, but you need to demand that the wave function is continuous.

So, if we call the three solutions $\psi_\text{I}(x)$, $\psi_\text{II}(x)$ and $\psi_\text{III}(x)$ from left to right in the domain $x$, we need to impose

$$ \psi_\text{I}(-a) = \psi_\text{II}(-a) $$

$$ \psi_\text{II}(a) = \psi_\text{III}(a) $$

Doing this you should get the result (I didn't check it myself).

Comment: The delta function makes it impossible to make the first derivative continuous.

Comment: Yes, right, I was thinking in a square well. That's the reason why we get two constants $A$ and $B$. I will correct it right now.